# IntelliJ's "Smart Tomcat" plugin does not "filter" resource files?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to use IntelliJ to deploy my multi-module application directly to a local Tomcat server (i.e. running on my laptop).

With the "Tomcat Server" run/debug configuration I could not get this working. The .jars of the other modules for some reason were not on the class-path and hence the application's startup always failed with a "class not found" exception. :-(

I then discovered that there also is a "Smart Tomcat" run/debug configuration variant. With that the entire application now seems to be on the classpath (the deployment descriptor file referenced during Tomcat's startup contains a huge "virtualClasspath=..." entry that contains all .jars from submodules and its maven dependencies) and the application indeed now starts up, BUT:

It now crashes during application initialization because obviously the resource files (e.g. `application.properties` from the root of the resource folder ending up in .../WEB-INF/classes of the deployed application) are not "filtered". I.e. these resource files still contain properties with `${placeholders}` that are normally supplied via maven settings during maven builds.

Is there a way to teach IntelliJ to read the maven settings and properties defined in the POM-file and use these values during its builds? Or teach it to let maven build these files before deploying them to Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix: Apparently my web module was missing the below resources snippet in its POM:

```
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
```

I had defined the above in the *parent POM* of all our modules but apparently that wasn't picked up properly by IntelliJ (I never had issues with that in plain Maven nor when using Eclipse...).
After adding such a snippet to the child-pom as well the module's resources are now properly filtered...

Bug or feature???